# How to change the color of the icons in the activity bar using settings.json

Tags: json, themes, visual-studio-code

I've been following this tutorial by Coder Coder to make my vscode look better
(tutorial link https://youtu.be/pGzssFNtWXw).
As per the video I've opened the settings.json file and just wrote some code
But when I try to change the color of the icons in the activity bar, nothing happens, here is the line of code I tried to use to change the color:`"activityBarBadge.foreground": "#000000"` this does not work though

Here is the code:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "editor.background": "#000814",
        "sideBar.background": "#000d20",
        "sideBarTitle.foreground": "#ffd60a",
        "sideBarSectionHeader.foreground": "#ffd60a",
        "activityBar.activeBackground": "#ffea81d5",
        "activityBar.background": "#22223b",
        "statusBar.background": "#ffd60a",
    }
```

Here is the result I got:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To change the Activity Bar icon colors use these two `colorCustomizations`:

`"activityBar.inactiveForeground"`

`"activityBar.foreground"`  // for the active icon

If you move the Activity Bar to the top (setting: `Workbench > Activity Bar: Location`) then you can use these colors:

```
"activityBarTop.foreground": "#0b1691",
"activityBarTop.activeBorder": "#ff0000",
"activityBarTop.inactiveForeground": "#ff0000",
```